# How to check whether my app is connected with Facebook or not

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, logging, facebook-android-sdk

This is the code of my Splash Screen and i want to check here if my app is logged in with Facebook.

```
package in.sincerity.prayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

    public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
            Handler handler =new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                }
            },2000l);
        }
    }
```

After finishing splash my login activity open.
The login Activity in my app which contains a facebook login button and it is working properly. It is logging in logging out successfully. My problem is when i close my app and reopen it the text of the fb button is "Log out" which means i'm already logged in to facebook and i don't need to do anything. How would i know whether i am logged in or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check whether an accessToken for facebook access.

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()!=null) {<you have logged on>}
```

Comment: My fb login button is showing "Log out" but Access.getCurrentAccessToken() is returning null.

Comment: Okay i get it. When i open the app for the first time it returns null although fb login button shows "Log out"  but after closing it and reopening it, it returns not null value. How to fix this ?

Comment: You will need to check whether you have instantiated the facebook sdk in the right place.         FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); should be done straight after         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Yeah, it is there just after super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Did you also all the facebook manifest items into the android manifest?

Comment: I'm sorry but i didn't get you ?

Comment: have you followerd all these steps : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

Comment: Yes i have followed each and every step.